# PHP-based graphing script recommendation

Tags: php, html

Can anyone recommend a easy to use php-based graphing script? I've been looking at [PHPGraphLib](http://www.ebrueggeman.com/phpgraphlib/examples.php) but I imagine there tonnes out there. Commercial or GNU, doesn't matter. Only requirement is  image based charts as these will be e-mailed/printed. (no flash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using [jpgraph](http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/) for some time - it allows you to do all sorts of things with your data. Needless to say this comes at the cost of a little complexity, but it is well documented and includes lots of examples. Its commercial for most purposes, but relatively cheap.

You might also consider [Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/) if your needs are very simple.

C.

Answer (score 0):

**[pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/)**

- Very nice graphics.
- Excelent Documentation.
- Easy of use.